# Raspberry Pi でリアルタイム機能を実装したい

Tags: raspberry-pi

接続は以下の通りです。

- センサー（8bit）=> GPIO
- GPIO => LED

アイデアとしては，「他の割り込みをさせないドライバにより，リアルタイム性を担保する」です。

自前ドライバは以下のようなアルゴリズムにします。

- `for(int i=0; i < n; i++)` でGPIOをポーリング
- 時系列でパターンマッチした瞬間にLEDをON
- n回に達したらbreak

以上のように，数秒程度ですがシステムがフリーズしますが，問題ないでしょうか？
あるドライバがコールされた際に，全ての割り込みを禁止するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
もしくは，他によい仕組みはないでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

μITRONを動かす方法もあります。
ITRONなので、リアルタイム性は抜群です。
http://domisan.sakura.ne.jp/article/rp_toppers/rp_toppers.html
https://www.kara-kuri.jp/blog/?p=1224
https://tech.nikkeibp.co.jp/it/atcl/column/16/060700122/062200039/

Comment: ありがとうございます。μITRONは「OSなしシステム」程度のリアルタイム性はありますでしょうか？数msecもしくは数usec程度の遅れの保証という仕様ではないでしょうか？また重要な点は，他の一切の割り込みを禁止した状況で，あるドライバが無限ループを実行してもよいか，です。この点については，いかがでしょうか？通常のOSでは許されず，μITRONでは許されるということでしょうか？

Comment: μiTRONはOSなしと同等のリアルタイム性を持たせることも可能です。優先度の高い割り込みハンドラーの中で無限ループも、開発者が認識していれば、可能です。また、ドライバーの中で無限ループすることは、どんなOSでもいいことではありませんが、Linuxと違って、すべて開発者が管理することが前提ですので、言ってみれば何でもありです。私ならGPIOの変化割り込みを使い、無限ループにはしないと思います。GPIOの変化割り込みの優先順位を最高にします。

Comment: GPIOの割り込みは，ステップやスパイクではなく，変化の時系列パターンですので，GPIOに張り付いている必要があります。
ところで，RapberryPiのメモリはリフレッシュなどが必要でしょうか？ハードでやっているのかドライバがやっているのか？
また，ユーザーのドライバがフリーズした場合，Wifiやbluetoothは大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: 「GPIOの割り込みは，ステップやスパイクではなく，変化の時系列パターンですので，GPIOに張り付いている必要があります。」とのことですが、ON,OFFの幅をチェックするには何らかのタイマーが必要ではないでしょうか？それともループの回数をタイマーとして使用するのでしょうか？おそらく私のイメージではGPIOの入力をシリアル入力のような目的で使うのだと思います。一般的にはGPIOの入力と同期しているクロック等を使って、それの割り込みでGPIOの状態を読み込み、処理を行うと思います。

Comment: お返事が遅くなりました。
while ループでポーリングするのですが，そのポーリングの間隔が一定なので，タイマーは不要だと考えています。

それで，Wifiやbluetoothのドライバも割り込みが必要だと思いますが，数分間それらへのコールを禁止しても，問題ないか検討してみます。

ありがとうございました。